# Compare SQL Database table Values without foreign key columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Hi I have two tables each one in different database.

Database Name : Database1
Table Name    : Employee

AND

Database Name : Database2
Table Name    : Employee

**In Database1 I have employee table as**

```
EmpSno  EmployeeID  EmployeeName    DeptID  DeptName

1           1           A             1     Technical
2           2           B             2     NonTechnical
3           3           C             3     Administration
```

and

**In Database2 I have employee table as**

```
EmpSno  EmployeeID  EmployeeName    DeptID  DeptName

1           4           A             4     Technical
2           5           B             5     NonTechnical
3           6           C             6     Administration
```

In the above two tables we have the same data, But the EmployeeID,DeptId column differ because It has different Id for both the column in their master table(EmployeeMaseter,DeptMaster).

Actually there is no difference between the tables. Is there any database compare tool that can achieve this. It should not show there is a difference between two tables.

Note: Using SQL Server 2012

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do it manually and just disregard the identity columns?

Create a query based on Name fields only, and use Except (twice) to find differences.

For example:

SELECT EmployeeName, DeptName FROM Database1.dbo.TableSomething
EXCEPT
SELECT EmployeeName, DeptName FROM Database2.dbo.TableSomething

As well as (with a union between them):

SELECT EmployeeName, DeptName FROM Database2.dbo.TableSomething
EXCEPT
SELECT EmployeeName, DeptName FROM Database1.dbo.TableSomething

This will give you all the differences.

Comment: I need this for all the tables under both databases. Databases has more than 10000 tables in each. So I need some tool to implement this.